# Are there any ready-made IAM policies for typical applications using CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

Are there any ready templates for IAM policies for typical applications using CLI ?

I mean templates that give basic permissions to use tools that are reasonably safe so that they do not give permissions to too many things.

For example - it wants to have access to create resources with  CloudFormation/Integrate Visual Studio Code, create/use Lambda/ApiGateway , run and disable instances ?

Answer (score 2):

There are some [managed policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html#aws-managed-policies) provided in IAM for some common job roles.

However, security is hard. It's a matter of giving required permissions without giving into temptation to just give all (`*`) permissions for a service.

Netflix created tools to monitor what permissions are being by particular IAM Roles, and then automatically reduce permissions to only what is necessary.

See: [Introducing Aardvark and Repokid - Netflix TechBlog](https://netflixtechblog.com/introducing-aardvark-and-repokid-53b081bf3a7e)

That would probably be overkill for your particular situation. All I can suggest is to start by only assigning permissions for services that are used. Then, for each service, think about the bad things that could happen by granting *too much* permission and then try to avoid that situation.

A common technique is to **separate dev/test from production** by putting them in different accounts. This way, production can be locked-down more than dev/test.

Comment: Thanks again for the useful information.

I'm going to give you a sample use case. I'm going to test/learn with this tool -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless  And now I'm never sure if it will always be "transparent" To be able to create resources I have to give administrative access. What policy (from managed policies ?) would you apply and is using third party resources (even if open source) not really dangerous in the long run?

Comment: The only way to be "not dangerous" is to keep dev/test separate from production. Then, use dev/test to learn what permissions are required, then grant minimal access for production. Sorry, but there is no easy answer to permissioning!

Comment: But how does the dev/test separate itself from production? at what stage is it done and how ? // edit separate account - you mean a new aws account for the same data/person or how ???

Comment: I thought of another potential solution. I don't know if it exists. Can I give permission to a service but it would have a limit? For example, that the permission will stop working when the free tier limit is exceeded etc ?

Comment: No. Services are not "aware" of their billing. A billing alarm can be created in Amazon CloudWatch, and a budget can be set in the billing system, but they do not impact/affect services. You code an AWS Lambda function to respond to such an alarm, which could shut-down infrastructure, but generally AWS users are more focussed on ensuring availability rather than halting services due to cost limits.

Comment: Dev/Test vs Production: Typically, developers who create systems are given access to Dev/Test systems. Actual production systems are run in a separate account to ensure security and to avoid accidents from impacting production systems. This is also true for traditional (non-cloud) infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. But I see a lot of cases when something suddenly gets out of control. What if a malicious code sneaks in and suddenly the bill jumps to cosmic proportions?. I guess it's better to breathe in the cold, am I right?

Comment: Permissions are normally used to control access to sensitive data and systems, rather than to "prevent runaway costs". For that, I would recommend billing alarms, budgets and forecasts.